# Python 3: Dict comprehension with if else and appending to a list

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, append, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries of the following structure:

```
myList=[{"ID": someString, "sequence": someString2, "quality":[5,6,7]},{...,'quality':[55,66,77]},...]
```

The quality has a list of numbers as value. The first number is representing the quality at position 0, the second at position 1 etc.

I want to create a quality-per-position Dictionary of the following structure:

```
qualityDict={0:[5,55], 1:[6,66],2:[7,77] etc}
```

my Idea:

```
qualityDict={}
for entryDict in myList:
        qualityDict={pos:[entryDict['quality'][pos]] if pos not in qualityDict.keys() else qualityDict[pos].append(entryDict['quality'][pos]) for pos in range(0,len(entryDict['quality']))}
```

The qualityDict is build as pos:[value] dictionary for each pos in range(0,length of the current quality). If the key is not already present in the dict, it is set and the value is set, if it is present, I want to append to the value.

So, after the first iteration for example, I have a dict with 0,1,2,3....length of first quality (which was iterated)  as keys and each key has a list with one value.
In the second iteration, I want to append the then current quality to the existing value's list.

I am getting an error for the appending part: 'NoneType' Object has no attribute append

What am I missing? Thanks :)

UPDATE: myList, which created the error:

```
[{'name': '@SRR587217.1 1 length=489', 'sequence': 'NTCCGGATGATGTCGCTGTTGCTGACAATGGTAATACGTTGACGGGGCAATATGCAGTTCGCTGCATACCGGTCCGACCCCGTACTGCTCACGCAGCTTATCCAGCAGTGGCATCATTTTTTCCAGAGGCGGTCGAACTCCGCCTTCGCAAAAAAAAAGGGAGCCCGGCGGAGGAGAACGTTACTGCGGCGGAGGTTACGATTTTTCCGGTTCCGCTCCTTTAGAAGCCGGACGTCTACCCGGCTCTTTTTGCTGAACGTCAGCGTCTGAAAGAGCTGGAACGTGAAAATCGTGAACTGCGCCGCAGTAACGATATCCTTCGCCAGGCTTCCGCTTATTTTGCGAAGGCGGAGTTCGACCGCCTCTGGAAAAAATGATGCCACTGCTGGATAAGCTGCGTGAGCAGTACGGGGTCGGACCGGTATGCAGCGAACTGCATATTGCCCCGTCAACGTATTACCATTGTCAGCAACAGCGACATCATCCGGA', 'optional': '+SRR587217.1 1 length=490', 'quality': [2, 20, 27, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 35, 33, 35, 35, 35, 35, 33, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 37, 38, 37, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 38, 39, 39, 39, 37, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 36, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 13, 6, 6, 6, 8, 15, 9, 9, 16, 8, 13, 23, 8, 15, 9, 9, 8, 8, 13, 13, 30, 9, 6, 20, 13, 6, 8, 15, 8, 9, 8, 13, 8, 23, 13, 23, 6, 13, 6, 6, 6, 20, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 15, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 13, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 15, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 15, 8, 30, 9, 9, 9, 8, 13, 19, 6, 15, 9, 8, 13, 8, 13, 6, 16, 25, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 6, 13, 6, 13, 15, 23, 9, 9, 9, 16, 9, 8, 6, 6, 13, 15, 9, 25, 9, 9, 9, 30, 30, 32, 32, 30, 33, 33, 33, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 40, 39, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 39, 40, 39, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 38, 39, 38, 37, 36, 37, 36, 34, 37, 32, 35, 39, 37, 39, 40, 39, 39, 37, 39, 33, 37, 38, 39, 39, 40, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 35, 36, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 37, 37, 39, 39, 38, 20, 32, 32, 36, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 33, 35, 29, 26, 34, 38, 38, 36, 38, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 38, 38, 38, 36, 36, 36, 30, 30, 36, 38, 36, 38, 36, 38, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 36, 36, 36, 38, 32, 32, 35, 32, 34, 27, 29, 35, 35, 17, 23, 32, 13, 19, 8, 25, 34, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 29, 35, 34, 34, 36, 34, 34, 34, 36, 25, 9, 30, 34, 36, 30, 27, 23, 36, 34, 34, 34, 38, 13, 24, 34, 34, 34, 38, 30, 34, 30, 30, 34, 30, 34, 36, 34, 36, 36, 36, 9, 24, 30, 36, 29, 23, 29, 17, 23, 30, 36, 36, 30, 30, 36, 35, 38]}, {'name': '@SRR587217.2 2 length=463', 'sequence': 'NACGAACCGATTCTGTTTGGTCTGCCAATTATCATGAACCCGGTGATGTTTATCCCGTTTGTACTGGTACAACCGATTCTGGCGGCAATCACCCTGGCAGCGTACTACATGGGCATTATTCCTCCGGTGACCAATATTGCACCGTGGACCATGCCAACCGGTCTGGGAGCCTTCTTTAACACCAACGGTAGCGTCGTCGCATTGCTGGTTGCACTCTTCAACCTTGGTATCGCAACGTTAATTAATTAACGTTGCGATACCAAGGTTGAAGAGTGCAACCAGCAATGCGACGACGCTACCGTTGGTGTTAAAGAAGGCTCCCAGACCGGTTGGCATGGTCCACGGTGCAATATTGGTCACCGGAGGAATAATGCCCATGTAGTACGCTGCCAGGGTGATTGCCGCCAGAATCGGTTGTACCAGTACAAACGGGATAAACATCACCGGGTTCATGATAATTGGC', 'optional': '+SRR587217.2 2 length=486', 'quality': [2, 20, 27, 30, 30, 30, 28, 27, 27, 27, 31, 35, 30, 33, 35, 30, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 34, 37, 39, 39, 36, 29, 34, 36, 39, 39, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 34, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 36, 37, 36, 25, 29, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 37, 33, 34, 34, 34, 36, 32, 35, 26, 29, 36, 36, 37, 36, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 35, 36, 37, 35, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 34, 36, 34, 32, 26, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 32, 36, 36, 37, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 35, 32, 30, 32, 36, 29, 30, 32, 35, 35, 36, 35, 35, 23, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 36, 23, 9, 25, 32, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 30, 34, 36, 36, 32, 30, 30, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 26, 29, 32, 36, 9, 23, 34, 37, 30, 30, 30, 32, 30, 33, 33, 30, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 34, 37, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 37, 37, 39, 40, 39, 38, 39, 37, 36, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 29, 29, 34, 36, 39, 39, 39, 40, 35, 26, 36, 36, 37, 36, 37, 32, 36, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 35, 34, 36, 32, 36, 33, 31, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 37, 36, 37, 37, 37, 33, 31, 34, 36, 36, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 36, 36, 36, 34, 32, 36, 32, 34, 32, 35, 30, 26, 35, 36, 37, 37, 25, 32, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 32, 36, 37, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 35, 37, 36, 29, 36, 37, 36, 36, 36, 37, 30, 32, 36, 30, 25, 34, 36, 35, 35, 35, 35, 29, 36, 34, 34, 36, 36, 36, 23, 32, 29, 32, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 32, 34, 36, 30, 25, 32, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 36, 25, 34, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 9, 30, 30, 29, 23, 23, 32, 25, 34, 32, 32, 36, 34, 9, 25, 34, 34, 36, 37]}, {'name': '@SRR587217.4 4 length=460', 'sequence': 'NTCCATGACTTCTGCACGCGTCGGCATCGGGTTAGTAATCATTGACTCCATCATCTGGGTCGCCGTGATTACCGCTCGGTTTAGCTGACGCGCACGACGGATCAACGCTTTCTGAATGCCGACCAGTTCCGGGTCGCCAATTTCCACACCGAGGTCGCCACGTGCAACCATTACCACGTCAGAGGCGAGGATGATGTCATCCATTGCATCCTGGCTGCAAACGGCTTCCGCACGTTCAACCTTGGCAACAAGTGATGCGAAAATTGTTGCCAAGGTTGAACGTGCGGAAGCCGTTTGCAGCCAGGATGCAATGGATGACATCATCCTCGCCTCTGACGTGGTAATGGTTGCACGTGGCGACCTCGGTGTGGAAATTGGCGACCCGGAACTGGTCGGCATTCAGAAAGCGTTGATCCGTCGTGCGCGTCAGCTAAACCGAGCGGTAATCACGGCGACCCAG', 'optional': '+SRR587217.4 4 length=502', 'quality': [2, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 33, 33, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 37, 39, 39, 40, 38, 38, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 39, 39, 36, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 39, 39, 39, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 32, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 23, 25, 34, 36, 36, 38, 36, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 34, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 35, 23, 29, 38, 38, 38, 38, 29, 35, 38, 36, 36, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 33, 33, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 34, 37, 39, 39, 39, 38, 39, 39, 40, 39, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 38, 39, 40, 39, 40, 38, 39, 39, 34, 35, 36, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 30, 35, 35, 37, 37, 37, 35, 37, 39, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 37, 36, 38, 38, 38, 33, 33, 38, 38, 36, 38, 34, 36, 34, 36, 36, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 35, 38, 38, 27, 32, 30, 34, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 23, 34, 38, 38, 36, 36, 34, 36, 38, 38, 38, 36, 34, 29, 36, 36, 36, 34, 34, 38, 36, 38, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 19, 23, 34, 36, 36, 30, 34, 16, 30, 36, 34, 29, 17, 23, 35, 35, 35, 15, 19, 23, 34, 34, 34, 36, 36, 34, 32, 38, 38, 23, 32, 38, 38, 38]}]
```

Kind regards to @balderman, example numbers taken from him

Comment: Could you please post actual values for myList that generate the error and the expected result?

Comment: added. when I do not put square brakets around my value (pos:[....]), it sets an integer as value (which fits for the first iteration) and then correctly gives me the error, that i cannot append to an integer. So, I am having trouble with getting my value as list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do this is with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). It wouldn't use dict comprehensions, but it would look like

```
from collections import defaultdict

myList = [...]  # as you described
qualityDict = defaultdict(list)

for entryDict in myList:
    for indx, qualNum in enumerate(entryDict['quality']):
        qualityDict[indx].append(qualNum)
```

To do this with dict comprehensions, you could make a separate `qualityDict` for each of the entries in `myList` and then union them somehow (but that would probably require more coding).

*Edit: a way with dict comprehensions*

Like I said before, the easiest way to do this with dict comprehensions would be to make a separate `qualityDict` for each entry, and then combine them somehow. I.e.

```
myList = [...] # as before
qualityDicts = []

# each entry gets a separate quality dict
for entryDict in myList:
    qualityDicts.append(
        {indx: qualNum for indx,qualNum in enumerate(entryDict['quality'])
    )

# now combine, not sure of a pretty way to do it with dict comprehensions
qualityDict = {}
for qdict in qualityDicts:
    for indx, qNum in qdict.items():
        qualityDict[indx] = qualityDict.get(indx, []) + [qNum]
```

Answer (score 1):

I made an assumption about how you data structure looks like.

Code below:

```
myList = [{'ID': 'someString', 'sequence': 'someString2', "quality": [5, 6, 7]},
          {'ID': 'someString1', 'sequence33': 'someString21', "quality": [52, 64, 77]},
          {'ID': 'someString13', 'sequenc3e': 'someString213', "quality": [532, 634, 
         737]}]

qualityDict = {idx: val['quality'] for idx, val in enumerate(myList)}
print(qualityDict)
```

Output:

```
{0: [5, 6, 7], 1: [52, 64, 77], 2: [532, 634, 737]}
```

Output (based on the updated 'myList'):

```
{0: [2, 20, 27, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 35, 33, 35, 35, 35, 35, 33, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 37, 38, 37, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 38, 39, 39, 39, 37, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 36, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 13, 6, 6, 6, 8, 15, 9, 9, 16, 8, 13, 23, 8, 15, 9, 9, 8, 8, 13, 13, 30, 9, 6, 20, 13, 6, 8, 15, 8, 9, 8, 13, 8, 23, 13, 23, 6, 13, 6, 6, 6, 20, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 15, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 13, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 15, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 15, 8, 30, 9, 9, 9, 8, 13, 19, 6, 15, 9, 8, 13, 8, 13, 6, 16, 25, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 6, 13, 6, 13, 15, 23, 9, 9, 9, 16, 9, 8, 6, 6, 13, 15, 9, 25, 9, 9, 9, 30, 30, 32, 32, 30, 33, 33, 33, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 40, 39, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 39, 40, 39, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 38, 39, 38, 37, 36, 37, 36, 34, 37, 32, 35, 39, 37, 39, 40, 39, 39, 37, 39, 33, 37, 38, 39, 39, 40, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 35, 36, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 37, 37, 39, 39, 38, 20, 32, 32, 36, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 33, 35, 29, 26, 34, 38, 38, 36, 38, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 38, 38, 38, 36, 36, 36, 30, 30, 36, 38, 36, 38, 36, 38, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 36, 36, 36, 38, 32, 32, 35, 32, 34, 27, 29, 35, 35, 17, 23, 32, 13, 19, 8, 25, 34, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 29, 35, 34, 34, 36, 34, 34, 34, 36, 25, 9, 30, 34, 36, 30, 27, 23, 36, 34, 34, 34, 38, 13, 24, 34, 34, 34, 38, 30, 34, 30, 30, 34, 30, 34, 36, 34, 36, 36, 36, 9, 24, 30, 36, 29, 23, 29, 17, 23, 30, 36, 36, 30, 30, 36, 35, 38], 1: [2, 20, 27, 30, 30, 30, 28, 27, 27, 27, 31, 35, 30, 33, 35, 30, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 34, 37, 39, 39, 36, 29, 34, 36, 39, 39, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 34, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 36, 37, 36, 25, 29, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 37, 33, 34, 34, 34, 36, 32, 35, 26, 29, 36, 36, 37, 36, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 35, 36, 37, 35, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 34, 36, 34, 32, 26, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 32, 36, 36, 37, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 35, 32, 30, 32, 36, 29, 30, 32, 35, 35, 36, 35, 35, 23, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 37, 36, 23, 9, 25, 32, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 30, 34, 36, 36, 32, 30, 30, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 26, 29, 32, 36, 9, 23, 34, 37, 30, 30, 30, 32, 30, 33, 33, 30, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 34, 37, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 37, 37, 39, 40, 39, 38, 39, 37, 36, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 29, 29, 34, 36, 39, 39, 39, 40, 35, 26, 36, 36, 37, 36, 37, 32, 36, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 37, 35, 34, 36, 32, 36, 33, 31, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 37, 36, 37, 37, 37, 33, 31, 34, 36, 36, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 36, 36, 36, 34, 32, 36, 32, 34, 32, 35, 30, 26, 35, 36, 37, 37, 25, 32, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 32, 36, 37, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 35, 37, 36, 29, 36, 37, 36, 36, 36, 37, 30, 32, 36, 30, 25, 34, 36, 35, 35, 35, 35, 29, 36, 34, 34, 36, 36, 36, 23, 32, 29, 32, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 32, 34, 36, 30, 25, 32, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 36, 25, 34, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 9, 30, 30, 29, 23, 23, 32, 25, 34, 32, 32, 36, 34, 9, 25, 34, 34, 36, 37], 2: [2, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 33, 33, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 37, 39, 39, 40, 38, 38, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 39, 39, 36, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 35, 39, 39, 39, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 32, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 23, 25, 34, 36, 36, 38, 36, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 34, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 35, 23, 29, 38, 38, 38, 38, 29, 35, 38, 36, 36, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 36, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 33, 33, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 34, 37, 39, 39, 39, 38, 39, 39, 40, 39, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 38, 39, 40, 39, 40, 38, 39, 39, 34, 35, 36, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 30, 35, 35, 37, 37, 37, 35, 37, 39, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 37, 36, 38, 38, 38, 33, 33, 38, 38, 36, 38, 34, 36, 34, 36, 36, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 35, 38, 38, 27, 32, 30, 34, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 23, 34, 38, 38, 36, 36, 34, 36, 38, 38, 38, 36, 34, 29, 36, 36, 36, 34, 34, 38, 36, 38, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 19, 23, 34, 36, 36, 30, 34, 16, 30, 36, 34, 29, 17, 23, 35, 35, 35, 15, 19, 23, 34, 34, 34, 36, 36, 34, 32, 38, 38, 23, 32, 38, 38, 38]}
```

Comment: Oh i need to clearify my desired result, sorry :( I want: {0:[5,52,532],1:[6,64,634],2:[7,77,737]} so sorry for not having it written better before :/

Comment: OK. Please make clear what is the exact output you are looking for. Introduce a reduced version of you input data structure so it will be easy to follow.